# JQuery: Change URL param without reloading?

Tags: jquery, url, url-rewriting

I have a question, is it possible to change the URL via JQuery under the following conditions:

- Same URL will load on browser back and on reloads
- Page doesn't reload when you change the parameter

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modify the URL without reloading the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wanna prevent the page from reloading you'll have to use hash "#"

And if you wanna change the URL try that:

```
jQuery.param.querystring(window.location.href, 'valueA=321&valueB=123');
```

This will return the following URL:

http://bla.com/test.html?valueA=321&valueB=123

Comment: @Anou I get error while doing this. `VM3398:2 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.param.querystring is not a function`

Comment: does this URL stays in history?

Comment: getting same error  Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.param.querystring is not a function

Answer (score 3):

I may be wrong but I think the browser will do a post if you change the location.

So, could it help you to use a post instead than a GET and change a hiddenfield/just set the value?

You can use jQuery.ajax() to make calls to the server setting the values you need in the post (or get, as you wish). That way the url doesn't change and you make the requests you need.

Comment: I'll sure give it a try! =) Thanks for the suggestion